# How to pass ID to image file name using MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to save my image File using `session ID` value and then in the **uploads** folder I want to pass the ID value like `3.jpeg or png`

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddImage(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
        {
            int compId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["compID"]);
            if (postedFile != null)
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                postedFile.SaveAs(path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName));
                ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully.";
            }

            return RedirectToAction("AddCompany");
        }
```

Below i have attached the image

[image: ID]

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: My question is like this .. save to folder 3.jpeg or png@OctoCode

Comment: As i think simple solution is `postedFile.SaveAs(path+compId.ToString()+System.IO.Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saving your image, you need to combine the compId and the file extension as follows:

```
    var filename = compId.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddImage(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
        int compId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["compID"]);
        if (postedFile != null)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            var filename = compId.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
            postedFile.SaveAs(path + filename);
            ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully.";
        }

        return RedirectToAction("AddCompany");
    }
```

Comment: I think this code make the file name like 3MyPic.jpeg but the he want to save MyPic.jpeg as 3.jpeg.

Comment: Actually it will just get the extension from the filename not the whole filename using the **Path.GetExtension** thus the final name would be compId plus the file extension